# Appropriate Local Storage for Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, local-storage, ionic3

I am reading about Local Storage and I am quite confused. As I see there are two options:

Native Storage , import { NativeStorage }
Ionic Storage, import { IonicStorageModule }
My app is developed with Ionic 3 and I am trying to save an array of object localy after retrieve it from Parse Server.

With Ionic 1 I stored the objects array like this:

```
setUsers (users){
    window.localStorage.users_data = JSON.stringify(users);
}
getUsers(){
   return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.users_data || '[]');
}
```

So now, what is the best option to save my data and stringfy them and parse them?

Native storage or Ionic Storage?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily use **Ionic** [**storage**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) module here. You just need to install  `SQLite` plugin. Details are in the above doc. Then you can use it natively on `iOS` and `Android` too without any issue.

**Usage:**

```
 // set a key/value
  storage.set('name', 'Max');

  // Or to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('age').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Sampath. But why to prefer IonicStorage than NativeStorage?

Comment: Because it is a module of `Ionic Team` and they maintain it with the framework changes.And they recommend it to use with Ionic. But the other plugin was 3rd party one. No guarantee about the maintainability.

Comment: can I use this for Ionic 3 and Firebase project?

Comment: Yes, You can, This is a generic pattern. You just need to follow the above steps.@metalhead101

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays I work with ionic 4 and I have experienced unpleasant latency of the **@ionic/storage** module, but after I switched to the **@ionic-native/native-storage** I got a better performance. And by the way you still can use it while testing with the browser using the **ionic cordova run browser** command not the **ionic serve** command.

So what I am trying to say that **native plugins** always win in the matter of performance.

Best Wishes