# Ionic 3 - How use ionic local storage for save data locally in device?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm triyng to make a introduction page that will read a QR Code, save the code and pass to another page. This will occur only the first time you open the application. When closing the app and reopen, the introduction page should not appears. So, what is my problem? I'm saving the code I read, but when I close the app and open again, the code that I had saved was lost and the introduction page appears. How do I solve this?

**Solutions I've tried to use**:

NativeStorage from @ionic-native/native-storage

IonicStorageModule from @ionic/storage

None of these solutions worked for me. The `IonicStorageModule` do not store any data and not returned any error when a use it. The `NativeStorage` worked for store data, but the saved data was not persistent, and when I close the application the data was lost.

**EDIT**:

My question is different from [Appropriate Local Storage for Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629594/appropriate-local-storage-for-ionic-3) because I'v already tried to use taht solution, but it not worked for me.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629594/appropriate-local-storage-for-ionic-3.

Comment: @fatemefazli I already tried using this solution, but it did not work. Did not return any errors, but did not save the data either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appropriate Local Storage for Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629594/appropriate-local-storage-for-ionic-3)

Comment: NativeStorage is the best option, data persist even after update the app, you're probably doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` but remember, when you clear localStorage `this.localStorage.clear();` or restart your app your data will be deleted.

**app.component.ts** or **login.ts**

```
if(localStorage.getItem('firstTime')){
   // Introduction page should not appears
} else {
   // Show introduction page
   // localStorage.setItem('firstTime', "1");
}
```

It's better to use [SQLite](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/).

Comment: But if I close the app and open again the data will be deleted?

Comment: @KimRuan `localStorage` can be deleted if device is low on storage, otherwise it stays in the browser. I use `localStorage` to show some data in sidebar, and that data is deleted only on logout function with `this.localStorage.clear();` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps,

```
npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

Add below code snippet to your app.module.ts,

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Add below code snippet to your example-page.ts,

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class ExamplePage {

  constructor(private storage: Storage, private platform: Platform,) {

platform.ready().then(() => {

// Save data to the storage
this.storage.set('yourStorageKey', data);

// Get data from the storage
     this.storage.get('yourStorageKey')
        .then(data => {
          console.log('your data => ', data);
        });

});
}

}
```

> NOTE: You should add code snippet for getting data from storage or
>   saving data to storage after platform ready.